# Epson XP 205 how do I install a driver & which one

Tags: wireless, drivers, printing, scanner

I am a novice user of Linux, but have successfully replaced Vista on my Gateway laptop(MT 6832b) with Ubuntu 12.04, everything seems to work o.k. ie -wifi to BB router(Tesco-Technicolor-router) E-mail , Music ,Photo's etc. The printing is working via USB only.I have an Epson XP205 Multi-function printer, I have downloaded a file from EPSON Support   :- epson-inkjet-printer-201202w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.src.rpm not sure if this is the correct one but how & where do I install it?
Will this then work fully as a scanner/copier/printer via wi.fi

Comment: ".rpm" is REDHAT. You need a file ending on ".DEB". But in general Linux does -not- require installation of drivers: either a printer is supported or it is not.

Comment: See if my answer works. If not PM me and I'll remove it.

Comment: Please fix your typos.

Answer (score 1):

**[Installation for Epson PX720WD Wireless Network Printing](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1719419)**. Your printer will have a similar method, except for the part in bold where you might want to check if you can find your printer.

> System -> Adminstration -> Printing and click Add to select New Printer
>
> Under Printer Type select Network Printer This will open a drop-down list. Select AppSocket/HP JetDirect
>
> This will show two text boxes called Host: and Port: for Host: you need to put the IP address of the printer. Leave the Port: as the default 9100
>
> You can determine the IP of the printer by pressing the Setup key on the printer, then select Network -> Network Settings -> Display > Wireless Summary If the printer is currently connected to the network, its IP address will be listed.
>
> Enter the IP address and select Forward
>
> Now you need to choose your printer driver.
>
> Under Manufacturer choose Epson Now for Model you will choose **Stylus
> Photo PX720WD**
>
> **It will suggest that you use the Epson Stylus Photo PX72OWD
> Series-epson-inkjet-printer 1.0.0-1lsb3.2 (Seiko Epson Corporation LSB
> 3.2) [en] (recommended) driver. This is correct. Click Forward and Apply**
>
> Unless your have the drivers installed already ignore the driver setup
> just below:
>
> **Describe Printer, enter the following details: Printer Name:
> Epson-Stylus-Photo-PX720WD-1 Description: Epson-Stylus-Photo-PX720WD-1
> Location: wherever Click Apply**
>
> Now you can go back to the printers box and right-click your new
> printer and select Make Default.
>
> Happy printing!